# Understanding a stored procedure SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i am trying to understand what a stored procedure is doing but i am struggling.

Here is the code

```
DECLARE
@person int,
@year int,
@default float = 0

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE PERSONID = @person AND YEAR1 = @year 
AND TYPE1 = 'A')
BEGIN
UPDATE Table1 SET DAY1 = @default
WHERE PERSONID = @person AND YEAR1 = @year AND TYPE1 = 'A'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Table1 (PERSONID, YEAR1, DAY1, TYPE1)
VALUES (@person, @year, @default, 'A')
```

This procedure takes data from a website and inserts it into a table into a database from my knowledge. But i cant see where it takes it from. Its just updating or inserting the existing table. Can anyone give any advice as to what this might be doing?

Thanks

Comment: The website that you have mentioned should be invoking the stored procedure you have mentioned here. To understand better you need to go through the website code and check how is calling is taking place and how the parameters are being passed.

Comment: The data is coming from the variables: `@person`, `@year` and `@default`. When doing an update, only `@default` is used, as `@person` and `@year` are used to find the correct row to update.

Comment: The procedure only uses data given as arguments when it is called. You should search for where and how the procedure is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `@person`, `@year` and `@default` are inputs to the stored procedure it is checking whether any record(s) exist in the `Table1` table with the specified `@person` and `@year` and the `Type1` field equal to the value `A`

If the record(s) exists it is updating that table's `Day` field with the specified `@default` value.

If the record(s) do not exist, it is inserting a new record with the specified `@person`, `@year` and `@default` and the `Type1` value of `A`.